# Google cloud launcher wordpress php.ini upload_max_filesize not working

Tags: php, wordpress, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-launcher

I tested out google cloud launcher one-click-installer and installed wordpress. Installation went fine, but when I used wordpress adming and tried to upload a theme file 22MB I got the message:

`The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.`

This is classic error message. I successfully made changes in the php.ini file to allow file uploads to 200MB. Saved changes and restarted apache. I even restarted the Instance but it didn't help. The problem were still there.

Does anyone knows what is the reason for this and how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 4):

Note that the additionally to `upload_max_filesize` you also have to increase the `post_max_size`. This `post_max_size` value manages the size of the whole POST request, so it is also necessary to increase it.

You can find the php configuration file in the following path:

`/opt/bitnami/php/etc/php.ini`

Once you have modified the configuration file, you have to restart the `PHP-FPM` service of your instance. You can do it by executing the following command:

`sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart php-fpm`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome! Just what I needed.

Comment: This solution is outdated (`/opt/bitnami` doesn't exist).

Answer (score 0):

For an instance created from GCP for WP instance the locaiton of PHP.ini file from terminal connected from SSH is on

```
/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini
```

`Line 656` for Post max = 100 M change to `4G`

`Line 809` for Upload_max_file_size = 100 M change to `4G`