# Increase PHP.ini file upload limit on Google Cloud Platform Kubernetes Wordpress Click-to-Deploy

Tags: php, wordpress, kubernetes

I deploy a one-click Wordpress Kubernetes application.
Now I want to upload Gravity-From Plugin.
But it gives me the error:

```
The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini
```

**How I am going to increase the PHP.ini file site so I can upload the plugin.**

Note : 
Github Repo: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/click-to-deploy

Screenshot of The Error : [image]

Screenshot Of Application:[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google cloud launcher wordpress php.ini upload\_max\_filesize not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37449497/google-cloud-launcher-wordpress-php-ini-upload-max-filesize-not-working)

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu Follow the below answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 4 ways that you can choose to increase the maximum upload file size in WordPress.

**1. Update .htaccess file**

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 128M

php_value post_max_size 128M

php_value memory_limit 256M 

php_value max_execution_time 300

php_value max_input_time 300
```

**2. Update wp-config.php file**

```
@ini_set( 'upload_max_filesize' , '128M' );

@ini_set( 'post_max_size', '128M');

@ini_set( 'memory_limit', '256M' );

@ini_set( 'max_execution_time', '300' );

@ini_set( 'max_input_time', '300' );
```

If you need more to learn follow the post.

https://help.servmask.com/2018/10/27/how-to-increase-maximum-upload-file-size-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 1):

For my situation, neither of the accepted answer solutions worked for me.  Adding `php_value` in `.htaccess` caused an error saying those additives weren't allowed there, and adding no additions to `wp-config.php` worked for me either.

The reason it seems to be for me is that apache is running all its php through a php-fpm engine (spotted the setting from the name of and in /etc/apache2/confs-enabled/php8.1-fpm.conf).  So, to get the settings to change, I needed to actually edit `/etc/php/8.1/fpm/php.ini` and change the settings in there instead.

After that, the change also wasn't picked up automatically, I had to restart fpm too `service php8.1-fpm restart`.