# GCP Wordpress Click to deploy VM - How to increase size upload limit

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

My firts question, so any feedback is appreciated
I want to use GCP Wordpress click to deploy VM to host a personal WordPress site. The problem I have is when I try to upload a theme. I'm getting the message: The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.

I have not been able to find and therefore edit the php.ini file.

So the questions:
How do I increase the file limit on a GCP VM WordPress click to deploy?
Where do I find the php.ini file?

I also have tried to upload the theme manually but Im worried that later I will have issues for not being able to upload more than 2mb files.

Any help would be appreciated

The details of the virtual machine:
e2 micro
29 gb persistent standart disk

I have tried the solutions posted here [Increase PHP.ini file upload limit on Google Cloud Platform Kubernetes Wordpress Click-to-Deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60679308/increase-php-ini-file-upload-limit-on-google-cloud-platform-kubernetes-wordpress)

Editing the wp-config.php file dindt solve the problem or as far I can tell any impact

Editing the .htaccess file (write the lines suggested in the middle of the script) made the wordpress server crash and unusable.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you can find the `php.ini` file being used by your Wordpress by hosting a a file named `whatever.php` in your Webserver's Document Root folder. Please put inside that file the following contents inside that file:

```php
<?php

phpinfo();
```

That's right, you don't have to close the `?>` short tags at the end of the file.

Then, hit that file through your `http://yoursite/whatever.php` address and check the output of where `php,ini` is set to.

- You don't have to use the `whatever.php` name for that file, use something obscure so only you know the name, once done, remove it from the path. I've made this example and list it here in this thread as a hypothetical file name, so, if you decide to rename `whatever.php` to something else, adjust your URL's accordingly when hitting it.
- If you have not yet configured a domain name for this Wordpress, your hostname will be your given Public IP Address.
- In that case, you should replace `http://hostname/whatever.php` with `http://x.x.x.x/whatever.php`, where `x.x.x.x` is your **assigned Public IP Address**.
- If your website is using TLS/SSL, you must start with `https://hostname/whatever.php` or `https://x.x.x.x/whatever.php`, note the extra `s` letter in `http`**s**`://`

If you think that's too much of a *hassle*, then **you can ssh into your VM** and **run** the following find command:

```bash
sudo find / -name php.ini -type f
```

You will most likely find the file at the `/etc/php/php.ini` path.

Then, edit the file with your preferred code editor. ***Hint****: `vim` ftw!*

**Tyoe:**

```bash
sudo vim /etc/php/php.ini
```

Then, hit `/`, this will activate `vim`'s powerful search feature.

Once that's done, find the proper entry `upload_max_filesize` hit `Enter`.

Once you find the entry, hit `I` as in `insert`.

Change it to the appropriate value you wish, make sure not to make it so big to avoid security issues later.

As a default, I think it starts with `2M`, but, this template may have it modified for Wordpress usage already, not sure.

Pick something like `100M` (100 megabytes) for its value, that's a lot for a single file IMHO, but some templates may need it.

Go figure. Adjust to something slightly bigger than your template's size amount, give it or take.

To save and close, first hit `Escape` then type `:wq`, as in Write and Quit!

Once done, either `reboot` the machine or run the following command:

If using a distro such as **CentOS** and **Apache** as the Webserver

```bash
sudo service httpd restart
```

If using a distro such as **CentOS** and **Nginx** as the Webserver

```bash
sudo service httpd restart
```

If using a distro such as **Ubuntu/Debian** and **Apache** as the Webserver

```bash
sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
```

If using a distro such as **Ubuntu/Debian** and **Nginx** as the Webserver

```bash
sudo systemctl restart nginx.service
```

This will reload the Webserver's configuration and so does PHP as it is a module for that Webserver.

That should do it.

*Hint:* You can also verify the PHP setting for `upload_max_filesize` inside of that phpinfo url `http://hostname/whatever.php`.

Use `Ctrl/Command +F` as the best Friend in such situations! Yay!

Comment: This answer has good information. Most systems will have more than one `php.ini` file. I recommend using the `phpinfo()` method in this answer to know which file is being loaded by PHP.

Comment: You are the man! I personally tried the SSH method and it worked!
Just a couple of notes for those like me who are new in this world of GCP, Vms, etc.

Comment: @Ernani you are the man! I personally tried the SSH method and worked!
Just a couple of notes for those like me that are noobs at this world of GCP, VMs, etc.
1. To get the right permission I needed to add sudo before the command find, so it looks like this: sudo find / -name php.ini -type f
2. There was 4 php.ini files, so it is necessary to check all 4 to make sure it will work
3. At the end I needed to reboot the entire VM using: sudo reboot

Anyways thanks so much @Ernani! You helped me when I was about to give up. Happy to be in GCP!

Comment: Thanks for the great feedback! I am not the man anyhow! I have just experienced some of these workloads in the past and wanted to pass some of the knowledge around! BTW, thanks for your tip on the step #1, I've totally missed the sudo before find when actually scanning for a root level path such as /. Great you are fine now and happy to join the GCP wagon!

Comment: Thanks! This was really useful in finding out which php.ini file my WordPress was using. I had like 4+ .ini files in the file system and this pointed me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

For WordPress deployed via official Google Click to Deploy image, you can follow these steps:-

1. SSH into your VM instance
2. Type in the command `sudo find / -name "php.ini"`
3. You will receive a list of files depending on your php version:

```
/etc/php/8.1/apache2/php.ini
/etc/php/8.1/fpm/php.ini
/etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini
/etc/php/8.1/cgi/php.ini
```

4. Edit the fpm/php.ini file using: `sudo nano /etc/php/<php version>/fpm/php.ini` and update the values.
5. Save the file and restart php and apache.

Note: If it doesn't work, try editing the values in `/etc/php/8.1/apache2/php.ini` as well.